# log request for "CORS policy execution failed"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

My ASP.NET Core 3.0 in a particular configuration/deployment logs:

> [INF] CORS policy execution failed.
>   [INF] Request origin https://bla.com does not have permission to access **the resource**.

How can I log at that point **the resource** that was requested for debugging ?

(note this question is *not* about the actual issue or solving it)
(note that I am not after globally increasing the log level etc)

Comment: Maybe you could try to set [log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-level) to Trace in appsettings.json file and appsettings.Development.json file to get more log details.

Comment: With a custom attribute or a middleware (before CORS's middleware)

Comment: @krlosmederos - how ?

Comment: Replace the default cors middleware with a custom middleware. More info here https://andrewlock.net/a-deep-dive-in-to-the-asp-net-core-cors-library/

Comment: can you share with us some code for you CORS Policy/Configuration ?

Comment: Just enable logging and configure as per example in official documentation. This should get started with necessary logs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration

Answer (score 2):

Well, that middleware is locked down pretty badly, and I haven't found any sensible way to hook into it.

If you want to replace the `CorsMiddleware`, you can't just create a decorator that calls `Invoke()` on the middleware, because you'll have no idea what happened.

Another solution might be to replace the `CorsService:ICorsService` registration in the service collection with a decorator, and then check the `CorsResult` after delegating the call to `EvaluatePolicy()`. That way you could emit an additional log message close to where the original message is emitted.

But there is another possible solution, both very simple and very crude: **To check what happened in the request.** Albeit that is a bit farther away from the original logged message.

The code below is a delegate added to the pipeline (in Startup/Configure, before `.UseCors()`) that checks if the request was a preflight request (the same way `CorsService` does), and if it was successful, i.e. the `AccessControlAllowOrigin` header is present. If it wasn't successful, it logs a message with the same `EventId` and source as the `CorsService`.

```cs
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    await next();

    var wasPreflightRequest = HttpMethods.IsOptions(ctx.Request.Method) 
        && ctx.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(CorsConstants.AccessControlRequestMethod);
    var isCorsHeaderReturned = ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(HeaderNames.AccessControlAllowOrigin);

    if (wasPreflightRequest && !isCorsHeaderReturned)
    {
        ctx.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .CreateLogger<CorsService>()
            .LogInformation(new EventId(5, "PolicyFailure"),
                $"CORS preflight failed at resource: {ctx.Request.Path}.");
    }
});
```

Based on my testing it seems to work. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

It might not be what you were looking for, but who knows, maybe it will be useful for someone.

*(Obviously a good way to deal with these things is to use a **structured logging** solution, like Serilog, and add enrichers to capture additional request information, or add stuff manually to a diagnostic context. But setting that up is quite a bit more involved.)*